# Creating an idempotent playbook that uses root then disables root server access

Tags: ansible

I'm provisioning a server and hardening it by disabling root access after creating an account with escalated privs. The tasks before the account creation require root so once root has been disabled the playbook is no longer idempotent. I've discovered one way to resolve this is to use `wait_for_connection` with `block`/`rescue`...

```yaml
- name: Secure the server
  hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.ipv4 }}"
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Block required to leverage rescue as only way I can see of avoid an already disabled root stopping the playbook
      block:
        - wait_for_connection:
            sleep: 2 # avoid too many requests within the timeout
            timeout: 5

        - name: Create the service account first so that play is idempotent, we can't rely on root being enabled as it is disabled later
          user:
            name: swirb
            password: {{password}}
            shell: /bin/bash
            ssh_key_file: "{{ssh_key}}"
            groups: sudo

        - name: Add authorized keys for service account
          authorized_key:
            user: swirb
            key: '{{ item }}'
          with_file:
            - "{{ssh_key}}"

        - name: Disallow password authentication
          lineinfile: 
            dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
            regexp: "^[\#]PasswordAuthentication"
            line: "PasswordAuthentication no"
            state: present
          notify: Restart ssh

        - name: Disable root login
          replace:
            path: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
            regexp: 'PermitRootLogin yes'
            replace: 'PermitRootLogin no'
            backup: yes
          become: yes
          notify: Restart ssh

      rescue:
        - debug:
            msg: "{{error}}"

  handlers:

    - name: Restart ssh
      service: name=ssh state=restarted
```

This is fine until I install `fail2ban` as the `wait_for_connection` causes too many connections to the server which jails the IP. So I created a task to add the IP address of the Ansible Controller to the `jail.conf` like so...

```yaml
- name: Install and configure fail2ban
  hosts: "{{hostvars.localhost.ipv4}}"
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - name: Install fail2ban
      apt:
        name: "{{ packages }}"
      vars:
        packages:
        - fail2ban
      become: yes

    - name: Add the IP address to the whitelist otherwise wait_for_connection triggers jailing
      lineinfile: dest=/etc/fail2ban/jail.conf
                  regexp="^(ignoreip = (?!.*{{hostvars.localhost.ipv4}}).*)"
                  line="\1 <IPv4>"
                  state=present
                  backrefs=True
      notify: Restart fail2ban
      become: yes

  handlers:

    - name: Restart fail2ban
      service: name=fail2ban state=restarted          
      become: yes
```

This works but I have to hard wire the Ansible Controller IPv4. There doesn't seem to be a standard way of obtaining the IP address of the Ansible Controller.

I'm also not that keen on adding the controller to every server white list.

1. Is there a cleaner way of creating an idempotent provisioning playbook?
2. Otherwise, how do I get the Ansible Controller IP address?

Comment: To get ansible controller IP address you can use: `{{ ansible_env['SSH_CLIENT'].split() | first }}`

Comment: Thanks. I did that in the end by changing gather_facts to yes and then using

    - set_fact:
      localhost_ipv4: "{{hostvars.localhost.ansible_default_ipv4.address}}"

Comment: If you found the solution to your problem, consider adding an answer to your own question.